# Unable to create a file in the Memory card

Tags: java, android, database, memory, android-sdcard

I'm trying to write data in the file and store it in the database. I tried out lots of codes online. But, I couldn't write the data. Can anyone please help me out. As of now I'm using the following code. I declared onClick="writemessage" and using the below code in the writemessage(View view) function. I'm running by connecting the mobile to the laptop. Can anyone please help me out.

```
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

  try {
        String filename = "abc.txt";
        String data = "Sensor data is found";
        File myFile = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
        if (!myFile.exists())
            myFile.createNewFile();
        byte[] data = string.getBytes();
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail** what "I couldn't write the data" means.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this permission in manifest file and handle run time permission.

```
       < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `AndroidManifest.xml` for this permission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and in your activity handle run time permission

```
private int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
```

Check for `Write External Storage Permission` before writing file on SD card.

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }else {
     //Write Data to SD Card
    }
```

and override `onRequestPermission` method of activity.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                this.finish();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is required.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;

    }
```